# llvm-gcc Error:Incompatible plugin

Tags: llvm, llvm-gcc

I am new to llvm.When I try to compile c programs using llvm-gcc i get following error:

$ llvm-gcc test.c

Incompatible plugin version
cc1: error: Fail to initialize plugin /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.5/plugin/dragonegg.so

I am using ubuntu-11.04,and llvm-gcc-4.5

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That means your dragonegg install is broken; compile your own, and/or complain to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dpkg-buildpackage to build your own llvm-gcc-4.5 and dragonegg debs. Another thing you may need to remember is changing the version in the debian/changelog file.